# Z-Index problem with media component in plugin config

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We have a little z-index problem with the media component in the plugin config.

[image]

Bug / Feature?

Seems to be a shopware bug.

Comment: Please remember that stackoverflow is not meant to be a place to report bugs :)

Comment: Next time please use the [issue tracker](https://issues.shopware.com/) or [GitHub issues](https://github.com/shopware/platform/issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed with this pull request. https://github.com/shopware/platform/pull/2716